# lapack-3.7.1 installation: zse2.out failed

Tags: ubuntu, gfortran, lapack

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04 and am attempting to install LAPACK-3.7.1 from latest lapack.tgz. I used the make.inc.example (copied to make.inc). `make` goes for a while, but then bombs with

```
Makefile:471: recipe for target 'zse2.out' failed
make[1]: *** [zse2.out] Error 139
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hercynian/Downloads/lapack-3.7.1/TESTING'
Makefile:42: recipe for target 'lapack_testing' failed
make: *** [lapack_testing] Error 2
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?